# Play Youtube Videos in Ionic 2

Tags: angular, youtube, youtube-api, ionic2

I want to display YouTube video in ionic 2. I am using [This](https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/youtube-video-player/) youtube native plugin. But videos are playing in full screen. And i want them to resize and fit into some div tag. So anybody help me how can i resize this default player?

Answer (score 0):

add api js

```
const doc = (<any>window).document;
let playerApiScript = doc.createElement('script');
playerApiScript.type = 'text/javascript';
playerApiScript.src = 'https://www.youtube.com/iframe_api';
doc.body.appendChild(playerApiScript);
```

then just do a regular youtube iframe api call on a random div

```
player = new (<any>window).YT.Player(divID, {});
```

Answer (score -1):

Here you can use the code, to play the video from youtube in iframe as per required dimension.

```js
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { IonicPage, NavController, NavParams } from 'ionic-angular';
import { FullvideoPage } from '../../pages/fullvideo/fullvideo';
import { VideoPlayer ,VideoOptions } from '@ionic-native/video-player';
import {SafeResourceUrl, DomSanitizer} from '@angular/platform-browser';
/**
 * Generated class for the ChaptersPage page.
 *
 * See http://ionicframework.com/docs/components/#navigation for more info
 * on Ionic pages and navigation.
 */

@IonicPage()
@Component({
  selector: 'page-chapters',
  templateUrl: 'chapters.html',
  providers:[VideoPlayer]
})
export class ChaptersPage {
videoOpts : VideoOptions ;
videoUrl: SafeResourceUrl;

  constructor(private domSanitizer: DomSanitizer, public navCtrl: NavController, public navParams: NavParams, private videoPlayer : VideoPlayer) {
  
  this.videoUrl = this.domSanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustResourceUrl('https://www.youtube.com/embed/aw5pMBeOWM0');
  }
  }
```

```html
<iframe width="100%" height="300" style="margin-left:-5% margin-right:-5%;" [src]="videoUrl" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
```

Comment: attach the proper screenshot with your code, so that i could able to get it.